# Problem Authenticating C# Facebook Example

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

First allow me to apologies for my lack of knowledge on this subject, but I am hoping to build this up!

I am having a lot of difficulty with the Facebook C# API. I am attempting to use the sample included in the download, "CSPASPNETWebsite." I have added my application ID and secret to the config file, and can run the site. I navigate to the login page and click the Facebook button, and then confirm that I wish to allow the app to access my data. However after doing this, I am never getting a positive result on being authenticated.

I have tried several things and keep having this problem, I was wondering if anyone else had had similar or knew what might be causing the problems. I would include code but it is exactly the example project with the config file adapted to my app.

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance for any responses.

EDIT: I should also note that I am developing locally, using Visual Studio 2010 and SDK version 5.0.3 (Beta). I have a suspicion that my problems may be due to the problem with cookies mentioned [here](http://facebooksdk.com/docs/2010/10/how-to-set-up-local-development-environment-for-facebook-application-development-using-asp-net/) however I cannot access IIS to try their suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Rob pointed out correctly that my opinion was wrong.
Infact I tryed playing a bit with the sample that he is mentioning and I have found that something weird happens navigating the same page with different browsers.
If I run the sample and browse it by google chrome it works as expected. 
Browsing it by ie 8 it doesn't work.

Moving the Fb:button after the script initialization it works in ie 8 too.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Log In
    </h2>

    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
        FB.init({ appId: '<%: Facebook.FacebookContext.Current.AppId %>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function (response) {
            if (response.session) {
                // A user has logged in, and a new cookie has been saved
                alert("right");
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                alert("wrong");
                // The user has logged out, and the cookie has been cleared
            }
        });
    </script>
    <p>
        <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

My original answer:
I believe your problems are not your fault.
It seems those examples are out of date. The one you are mentioning is built on top classes deleted from the last version of the sdk.
Lately the sdk has been completely changed and code examples are not updated.
You can see here, for the one you are mentioning how many changes has been made:

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

for instance

> - updated CSASPNETWebsiteregistrationForm to use
>     Request.GetFacebookSignedRequest()
>     method
> - CSASPNETWebsite to use FacebookAuthorizer instead of
>     Authorizer

If you would like to see that example working I think you should remove references to the last build of the sdk and reference the old one.

I dont raccomand it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jack, I am not exactly sure that is the issue though - the project is not very complicated, and does not give any reference errors at all. In fact, the application works as it should do, except that the login is not stored. The symptoms would perfectly match the problem noted in the link I added in the orginal post.

Comment: Interesting! I'm using Firefox and don't have the ability to install Chrome to test that, but using IE7 going to the login page causes the page to constantly refresh. The facebook login popup never seems to resolve. Naturally, the login doesn't work. I tried switching the facebook button to be after the script, but still no luck in firefox. Thanks again though, really appreciate your help